# Android Capture and upload getting only low quality image

Tags: php, android, android-studio

I want to make a android app that captures and uploads image to server, My code is working fine, i.e i can capture image and submit it to server using http post method .

**But the problem is... In my server, it's only getting image with low quality, actual image is almost 500-900Kb. But the uploaded size is only 5-10kb**

-preview within the app also shows low quality image. I don't want to compress or resize. i need the actual size image on my server

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnCamera:

            Intent cameraintent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraintent, 101);
            break;
        case R.id.btnSubmit:
            if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                if (!upflag) {
                    Toast.makeText(ImageActivity.this, "Image Not Captured..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    saveFile(bitmapRotate, file);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ImageActivity.this, "No Internet Connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    try {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 101:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        selectedImage = data.getData(); // the uri of the image taken
                        if (String.valueOf((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data")).equals("null")) {
                            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                        } else {
                            bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                        }
                        if (Float.valueOf(getImageOrientation()) >= 0) {
                            bitmapRotate = rotateImage(bitmap, Float.valueOf(getImageOrientation()));
                        } else {
                            bitmapRotate = bitmap;
                            bitmap.recycle();
                        }

                        ivImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        ivImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapRotate);

// Saving image to mobile internal memory for sometime
                        String root = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().toString();
                        File myDir = new File(root + "/androidlift");
                        myDir.mkdirs();

                        Random generator = new Random();
                        int n = 10000;
                        n = generator.nextInt(n);

//Give the file name that u want
                        fname = "sg" + n + ".jpg";

                        imagepath = root + "/androidlift/" + fname;
                        file = new File(myDir, fname);
                        upflag = true;
                    }
                }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Bitmap retVal;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    retVal = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    return retVal;
}

//    In some mobiles image will get rotate so to correting that this code will help us
private int getImageOrientation() {
    final String[] imageColumns = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION};
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int orientation = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION));
        System.out.println("orientation===" + orientation);
        cursor.close();
        return orientation;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

//    Saving file to the mobile internal memory
private void saveFile(Bitmap sourceUri, File destination) {
    if (destination.exists()) destination.delete();
    try {

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        sourceUri.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            new DoFileUpload().execute();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ImageActivity.this, "No Internet Connection..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class DoFileUpload extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ImageActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("wait uploading Image..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            // Set your file path here
            FileInputStream fstrm = new FileInputStream(imagepath);
            // Set your server page url (and the file title/description)
            HttpFileUpload hfu = new HttpFileUpload("http://www.example.com/test/save.php", "ftitle", "fdescription", fname);
            upflag = hfu.Send_Now(fstrm);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // Error: File not found
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (upflag) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploading Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Also there is no image compression or resize in my php script

Comment: You are number #### who reports this problem. Your problem is reported at least two or three times every week. So a little googling would have given you all these posts. Your start intent is wrong to begin with as you should give it an extra output parameter telling where the picture should be stored. After that you can use the supplied file path to upload a file instead of a bitmap.

Comment: Yeah I got it  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitmap in the extras under the key "data" contains only thumbnail of the picture.

Read this article: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath